# LotusScript to alter Sametime Server Community

Tags: lotusscript, sametime

Can someone give or direct me to LotusScript that will allow me to add\remove a Sametime Server Community. We have to update all employees to the new Sametime server we have created. Probably half the people will screw up the install of a new Server Community, so I want to automate it if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at creating a desktop policy settings document to specify a Sametime server for users.

From the Administrator help:

> Enter the server name in the Sametime server field. When pushed down
>   to the users, this setting populates the field "Sametime server" in
>   the users' Location documents.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you should use desktop policies for this task. In addition there is also available managed setting tab, where you can put settings for the embedded Sametime plug-in. For example, I have used the following settings:

> com.ibm.collaboration.realtime.community/host=SAMETIME_SERVER_HOST_NAME;
>   com.ibm.collaboration.realtime.community/name=SAMETIME_SERVER_HOST_NAME;
>   com.ibm.collaboration.realtime.community/port=1533;
>   com.ibm.collaboration.realtime.community/loginByToken=true;
>   com.ibm.collaboration.realtime.community/loginAtStartup=true;
>   com.ibm.collaboration.realtime.login/autologin=true;
>   com.ibm.collaboration.realtime.login/resetUser=true;